# WordPress custom post type URL rewriting with custom field values

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I can't seem to get this to work how I want it to, but here's basically what I want to do:

I have a page called "album". This has all of the photo albums on that page. Then you click an album to go to the photo gallery for that album. I have a custom template for this page set, so all of the different albums will use this template. From here, I want to be able to click on an image and take it to the single image view. Because the photo gallery page is a custom post type, when I go to the single image, I have a file called "single-gallery.php" which then should display and then gather the image data to display it.

This is all working, however I want to keep the URL a certain way throughout this. I have almost got it how I want it, however the issue I am having is that I need to rewrite the URL in the gallery custom post type and use a custom field value in the URL to indicate which album this is.

For registering my "gallery" custom post type, I have this to rewrite my URL:

`'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'album/%albumName%','with_front' => true),`

Then in the gallery page template I use php to replace `%albumName%` with the current album.

`$photoPermalink = str_replace('%albumName%', $albumName, $photoPermalink);`

The problem is that I guess WordPress has to index the permalinks, and it's indexing the `%albumName%`, so when I change it with PHP it gets broken.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wordpress's own filters to do this. At least to do it correctly without causing issues in other areas of your wordpress install later.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types

That actually shows you how to create custom permalink structures for custom post types.

Comment: Down vote? Someone doesn't like that they shouldn't be using str_replace for the permalink structure of a custom post type? lol

Comment: The answer on the link doesn't really make sense to me